# Whats wrong with importing font in expo project

Tags: expo

I tried to use Montserrat as a font, but faced Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet, Text, View, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity, TextInput
} from 'react-native';

import { Feather } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

export default function App() {

  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    Montserrat: require('./assets/Montserrat-Regular.ttf'),
  });

  if (!loaded) return null;
  
  return(
<Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontFamily: "Montserrat"}}>Hello</Text>
  );
}
```

Please help me fix it. Or if you know another way to use font, please tell about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [expo-fonts](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/#installation). From there, I suggest making a custom text component that you will use whenever you need text.

```
import { useFonts } from 'expo-fonts';

function MyText() {
 const [loaded] = useFonts({
    Montserrat: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf'),
  });

  if (loaded) {
    return <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Montserrat' }} />;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: ×
Error: MyText(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: I updated the component to return null if it isn't loaded. That should fix the current error

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet and add fonts in you Assets. You can load images also

```
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const [isLoadingComplete, setLoadingComplete] = useState(false);

  async function loadResourcesAsync() {
    await Promise.all([
      Asset.loadAsync([
        require('./assets/images/image.png'),
      ]),
      Font.loadAsync({
         Montserrat: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat.ttf'),
      }),
    ]);
  }

  function handleLoadingError(error) {
    // In this case, you might want to report the error to your error reporting
    // service, for example Sentry
    console.warn(error);
  }

  function handleFinishLoading() {
    setLoadingComplete(true);
  }

if (!isLoadingComplete) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadResourcesAsync}
        onError={handleLoadingError}
        onFinish={() => handleFinishLoading(setLoadingComplete)}
      />
    );
  }
  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontFamily: "Montserrat"}}>Hello</Text>
    </View>
  );

}
```